# Is it possible to inline a subroutine from the intel mkl library?

Tags: inline, subroutine, intel-mkl

My code calls the Intel MKL dgemv many times. Is it possible to inline the MKL dgemv?

Answer (score 0):

In general, compilers will not inline BLAS calls at the source level but the linker can do it under some circumstances.  However, I've heard that Intel is providing some support for inlining MKL in C code in the version 15 release of the compiler.  But you'll have refer to the official documentation for confirmation and details.